# aioredis under uvicorn with uvloop question

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn, uvloop, aioredis

I have a question. If I use aioredis together with FastAPI using uvicorn and set uvloop in the --loop argument, will aioredis use uvloop or pure asyncio?

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/get/{key}')
async def get_from_redis(key):
    redis = aioredis.from_url('redis://127.0.0.1')
    value = await redis.get(key)  # uses uvloop or pure asyncio?
    return {'response': value}
```

```
uvicorn main:app --workers 2 --loop uvloop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will use `uvloop`.

Uvicorn runs `asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(uvloop.EventLoopPolicy())` before starting the application.